# Need to edit attribute value for a node in an xml file

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to edit an attribute value in a XML file with the id of the user logged in

i tried :

```
$user = $env:USERNAME
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "D:\Python\prm.xml")
$node = $xml.BootStrap.DataBaseAliases.LastLoginUserName
$node.SetAttribute("LastLoginUserName", "$user");
```

It returns an error :
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Python\a.ps1:5 char:1
+ $node.SetAttribute("LastLoginUserName", "$user");
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Also tried following:

```
$user = $env:USERNAME
$FileLocation = "D:\Python\prm.xml"
$File = Get-Content $FileLocation
$XML = [XML]$File
$XPpath = "/BootStrap/DataBaseAliases/LastLoginUserName"
$node = $XML.SelectNodes($XPpath)
$node | % { $_.SetAttribute("attribute-1", "$user") }
$XML.OuterXml | Out-File $FileLocation
```

This doesnt return any error, but xml is unchanged.
XML content below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BootStrap MajorVersion="18" 
MinorVersion="8" PatchVersion="5" DeploymentVersion="0"><DataBaseAliases 
DefaultPMAlias="Corp_2016" LastLoginUserName="FOOUSER"><Alias>
<Name>PMDB</Name><AppType>Project Management</AppType><Connection> 
<DriverName>SQLServer</DriverName><BlobSize>-
```

i would like to replace FOOUSER with user currently logged in.

Comment: Thanks,Fixed the typo, but now it returns the below error:
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'SetAttribute'.
At D:\Python\a.ps1:5 char:1
+ $node.SetAttribute("LastLoginUserName", "$user");
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath is not pointing to proper an element, so the result is an empty set. Let's see why.

`/BootStrap/DataBaseAliases/LastLoginUserName` would match XML like so,

```
<BootStrap>
  <DatabaseAliases>
    <LastLoginUserName />
  </DatabaseAliases>
</BootStrap>
```

That's not what is in the sample. `LastLoginUserName` is an *attribute* of `DatabaseAliases`. Change the XPath to point into DataBaseAliases element and set its properties, like so:

```
$XPpath = "/BootStrap/DataBaseAliases"
$node = $XML.SelectNodes($XPpath)
$node | % { $_.SetAttribute("LastLoginUserName", $user) }
$XML.InnerXML
```

Comment: perfect, works like a charm, Thanks for your help with this